# How this expression is evaluated in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I know operator priorities for the ones I used in this expression:

```
if (typeof day === "undefined" || notifiedday !== weekday) //do something
```

> **===**  10
>   
>   **||**       5
>   
>   **!==**  10

source https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

I know in C++ **during the code execution** this expression would work like this:

```
if (typeof day === "undefined")
{
  if(notifiedday !== weekday)
  {
   //do something
  }
}
```

I am still not sure how this would work in JavaScript during the runtime.

Comment: @Teemu I know, I wrote numbers near

Comment: @Alnitak you mean there is no difference between the execution context

Comment: The snippets are not equivalent. The latter is rather equivalent to logical AND in JS.

Comment: sorry, I was unclear, I meant it works just the same as in C++, although you're correct that the OP's C++ snippet is itself incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same in JS as it does in C++. Though the example you added to your question is wrong, it should be:

```
if (typeof day === "undefined"){ // do something }
else if(notifiedday !== weekday){ // do same thing }
```

What you wrote is equivelant to

```
if (typeof day === "undefined" && notifiedday !== weekday){ //do something }
```

### Or functionality

```
if(typeof day === "undefined" || notifiedday !== weekday)
```

Since or is used, only one of them needs to be true for the expression to be true. So if `typeof day === "undefined"` is true then `notifiedday !== weekday` doesn't need to be checked but if `typeof day === "undefined"` is false then both items need to be checked.

### And functionality

```
if(typeof day === "undefined" && notifiedday !== weekday)
```

Since and is used, both of them need to be true for the expression to be true. So if `typeof day === "undefined"` is false then `notifiedday !== weekday` doesn't need to be checked since `and` needs both, but if `typeof day === "undefined"` is true then both items need to be checked.

Comment: Yes probably I wrote the case with &&

Answer (score 0):

The comparison is ended when the result is clear.

```
if (false && true) {  } //true won't be evaluated since the left side of the operation gave the final result

if (true || false) {  } //false won't be evaluated since the left side of the operation gave the final result
```

And it works the same for multiples statements

```
if (false || (false && true)) {  } // both falses are evaluated, the true won't be.
```